# Excel not exporting, using react-data-export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export, export-to-excel

I'm trying to make an excel export but for some reason it is not working at all, I'm using [react-data-export](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-export) and I was trying to do a small test using this as an [Example](https://github.com/securedeveloper/react-data-export/blob/HEAD/examples/simple_excel_export_01.md) but it didn't work at all.

This is my button:

```
 <Button 
      startIcon = {<FileDownloadIcon />} 
      variant = "contained" 
      color = "success" 
      size = "medium" 
      onClick={exporExcel} >
      Exportar Excel
 </Button>
```

and this is my function:

```
const exporExcel = () => {
      <ExcelFile>
        <ExcelSheet data = {pedidos} name = "Prueba">
        <ExcelColumn label="# Pedido" value="id"/>
        <ExcelColumn label="Estudiante" value="nombre"/>
        <ExcelColumn label="Colegio" value="escuela"/>
        <ExcelColumn label="Grado" value="grado"/>
        </ExcelSheet>
      </ExcelFile>
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the button on ExcelFile tag, like this

```
<ExcelFile element={<YourCustomButtonComponent />}>
    <ExcelSheet data = {pedidos} name = "Prueba">
    <ExcelColumn label="# Pedido" value="id"/>
    <ExcelColumn label="Estudiante" value="nombre"/>
    <ExcelColumn label="Colegio" value="escuela"/>
    <ExcelColumn label="Grado" value="grado"/>
    </ExcelSheet>
</ExcelFile>
```